# python synthesize midi with fluidsynth

Tags: python, midi, synthesizer

I can't import fluidsynth. [Maybe there's an better module?]

I'm trying to synthesize midi from python or pygame. I can send midi events from pygame.
I'm using mingus, and it seemed pyfluidsynth would be good / easiest.

I think this means pyfluidsynth is installed, but a seperate fluidsynth was not. I don't know if it requires a 'fluidsynth' installer to work?

test.py:

```
import fluidsynth
print ":("
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import fluidsynth
  File "C:\Users\jake\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\fluidsynth.py", line 34, in <module>
    raise ImportError, "Couldn't find the FluidSynth library."
ImportError: Couldn't find the FluidSynth library.
```

using: python 2.7-win32

Comment: did you try https://github.com/MostAwesomeDude/pyfluidsynth ?

Answer (score 3):

The python fluidsynth module is looking for the FluidSynth binary library file (ie fluidsynth.dll).

To get this you can download, compile and install http://sourceforge.net/projects/fluidsynth/files/fluidsynth-1.1.3/

OR

you may be able to find projects using fluidsynth (ie QSynth) which include precompiled copies of the .dll file.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you need the FuildSynth lib also (dll for windows).

To make it works with:

- fluid synthsynth 1.1.6
- python26 (32bits)
- pyFluidSynth 1.1.4
- Windows

I've put everythings in the same directory (fluidsynth dll, PyFluidSynth Module, python script).

and changes the following lines in the pyFluidSynth modules (from line 30) :

```
# A short circuited or expression to find the FluidSynth library
# (mostly needed for Windows distributions of libfluidsynth supplied with QSynth)
# and Dynamically link the FluidSynth library

lib = find_library('fluidsynth') or find_library('libfluidsynth') or find_library('libfluidsynth-1')
if lib is None:
   _fl = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("./libfluidsynth")
   lib = "ok";
else:
  _fl = CDLL(lib)   

if lib is None:
    raise ImportError, "Couldn't find the FluidSynth library."


# Helper function for declaring function prototypes
```

It works fine with this setup.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at `fluidsynth.py`, your guess is probably right.
You should try putting `fluidsynth.dll` somewhere in your system's library search path (the easiest would probably be the same directory as your script or `fluidsynth.py`).

I think this archive (found via google) contains the necessary win32 binary: http://svn.drdteam.org/zdoom/fluidsynth.7z